# Setting different Start Menu icon in NSIS script?

Tags: nsis

Is it possible to use a different icon for the Start Menu shortcut versus the Desktop shortcut in NSIS?

On the desktop, the shortcut is perfect size, at 48x48. However in the start menu, the icon gets sized down to what I'm assuming is 32x32 and looks choppy.

```
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${NAME}.lnk" \
             "$INSTDIR\$(shortcut_name).lnk"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${NAME}.lnk" \
             "$INSTDIR\$(shortcut_name).lnk"
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: You example code does not make sense, you are creating a shortcut to a shortcut.

Comment: I suppose it's because I've already done a CreateShortcut with the execution arguments and ico before these statements, that this code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows icon can contain multiple images with different sizes, your icon should ideally contain 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 128x128 and 256x256 pixel images.

The size of icons on the desktop and start-menu depends on system settings and DPI.

For most installers you would just use `CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\myapp.exe"` and myapp.exe would have the icon in its resources. You can also use a external .ico file: `CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\myapp.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\myapp.ico" 0`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the specification for [CreateShortcut](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#createshortcut) you'll see that the arguments are as follows.

`[/NoWorkingDir] link.lnk target.file [parameters [icon.file [icon_index_number [start_options [keyboard_shortcut [description]]]]]]`

Since you don't have any parameters I believe you will have to pass an empty string to that. So something like this will probably do it.

```
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${NAME}.lnk" \
    "$INSTDIR\MyApplication.exe" \
    "" \
    "$INSTDIR\MyApplication.exe"`
```

Or if you have another icon in your main executable and want to use that you can specify an index after the icon path like this.

```
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${NAME}.lnk" \
    "$INSTDIR\MyApplication.exe" \
    ""\
    "$INSTDIR\MyApplication.exe" 2`
```

Comment: You cannot specify the icon index like that, you need to add "" for unused parameters...

Comment: The icon index is the next parameter after the icon file, so why shouldn't it work? I also specified the the empty parameter as "" but since he used line breaks in his sample I did it the same way here..

Comment: Yeah, I was confused by your .lnk usage. You cannot link to a link with CreateShortCut, that is, the 2nd parameter cannot be a .lnk

Comment: True, I just kept his original targets but added a comment about it. I've changed it to point to an .exe now to make it clearer.